# can i limit the active service in a swarm to 1 instance?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

i’m currently in the process of setting up a swarm with 5 machines. i’m just wondering if i can and should limit the swarm to only allow one active instance of a service? and all others just wait till they should jump in when the service fail.

This is to prevent potential concurrency problems with maria-db (as the nodes sill write to a nas), or connection limit to an external service (like node red with telegram)

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying with stack files you can set "replicas: 1" in the deploy section to make sure only one instance runs at a time.
If that instance fails (crashes or exits) docker will start another one.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#replicas

> If the service is replicated (which is the default), replicas
> specifies the number of containers that SHOULD be running at any given
> time.
>
> ```
> services:   frontend:
>     image: awesome/webapp
>     deploy:
>       mode: replicated
>       replicas: 6
> ```

If you want multiple instances running and only one "active" hitting the database you'll have to coordinate that some other way.

Comment: this does seem to do the trck.I've done some testing with a testswarm and pulling the plug on one of the worker after.

However, it can take a long time before replica has pulled the image and build up the node. Is there a way to have all nodes prepare the task nevertheless so they dan take over at any time?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to force it to pre-prepare images.

Comment: Male sure you use order: stop-first for update_config and rollback_config